# Npgsql : is the server down or a bad password?

Tags: c#, .net, database, postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to connect to `PostgreSQL` database from my c# application like so:

```
NpgsqlConnection MyConnection = new           
NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=mypassword;Database=mydatabase;");
try
{
    MyConnection.Open();
}
catch (NpgsqlException pe)
{              
    //Code "28P01" = user name or password is wrong 
    // server ip or port  is wrong
}
```

the question is : NpgsqlException.code does not differentiate between the following conditions:

1. server ip /port number is wrong
2. user name and password combination is wrong

Code "28P01" is returned in both cases. obviously Npgsql can see that the server is there and responding with some data indicating bad user name or password  (condition #2 above) or nobody seem to be there (condition #1 above)

how can i differentiate between those 2 cases in my code?

Comment: you could try to manually open a TCP connection...

Comment: yup ,but that will only tell me that something is listening on that port. i wouldn't tell me what is listening. e.g. there could be MySQL database there !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with Npgsql v 3.0.2.0 (not sure about older versions) if the IP/hostname is wrong an Exception with code =-2146233083 with be thrown. if however the IP/hostname is correct but the port number is wrong Exception with code= -2147467259 with be thrown. if the IP/port is correct but username /password is wrong a NpgsqlException with code = "28P01" will be thrown.

Comment: Embedding long numeric error codes is a sure way to know you're doing something wrong. If the IP exists and the port is wrong, you will get a SocketException with SocketErrorCode equal to SocketError.ConnectionRefused (see test https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/develop/test/Npgsql.Tests/ConnectionTests.cs#L137). If there is no server at the given IP then the connection attempt will in general time out, throwing a TimeoutException (see test https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/develop/test/Npgsql.Tests/ConnectionTests.cs#L243).

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using Npgsql 2.x; the new Npgsql 3.x throws NpgsqlException only when errors are received from a PostgreSQL server. Network connection errors are raised as SocketException etc. You're encouraged to upgrade.

By the way: I couldn't reproduce your exact findings even with Npgql 2.x, connecting to a wrong port or a wrong IP resulted in an NpgsqlException with Code being an empty string, not 28P01.

Comment: i was using Npgsql 2 when i started my project a month ago. now i am using Npgsql v 3.0.1.0 as indicated by visual studio

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a PostgreSQL listening at your host and port? Npgsql doesn't just manufacture NpgsqlExceptions with code 28P01...

Comment: you are right. someone have already posted some exception codes above.